# How to use special characters in PHP in a command shell?

Tags: php

For school we are forced to write a small program in BASIC or "any other language" so I will be doing it in PHP.

I have to run it through command prompt, so thought I'd make a few improvements to the "UI" of the shell with lines etc. I used ALT+nnn to insert them into my code, but when I execute it in the shell I get weird characters in it's place.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you mean you're trying to use terminal control sequences?

Comment: Do you mean you want to output ASCII line graphics from PHP?

Comment: Yes nikc.org that's what I would like :)

Comment: I think he means he has non-ASCII characters hardcoded in the source. That won't work.

Comment: write it in assembler, freak the teacher out.

Comment: I didn't think it'd work. Does anyone know how I could force it to work in command shell on Windows XP? I doubt she'd be happy with me installing a LAMP stack on top of it..

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/137626)

- switch font to Lucida
- then to switch shell code page to UTF-8, type:

  `chcp 65001`

This seems to be very buggy on Windows, so you are maybe better with codes like [850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (Latin-1, the MS-DOS equivalent of 1252 in Windows). I mean `chcp 850`.

Comment: I have done this, but as soon as I tried to run the program I get an error telling me "-f" isn't a internal or ext. command. Can you please tell me how to reset it back to ASCII please?

I guess my teacher will just have to make do with an ugly "UI".

Comment: Try `chcp 437`, should be `US-ASCII`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not to worry, it's only a small program for a school and nothing a client will ever see!

Comment: Did you try `chcp 1252`? Seems to work for another SO user: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1650454/137626 and after all `cmd` is a Windows shell running in Windows, not MS-DOS 7 or whatever.

Comment: Something is seriously up with my cmd.exe now it doesn't recognize that command (CHCP) or php.exe. I will have to do some digging.