# Python to remove all <p> instances in a string using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the code below to get the following

```
<p>Ibn Umar reported: I passed by the Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be
 upon him, while my garment was trailing. The Prophet said, ÔÇ£<b>O Abdullah, ra
ise your garment</b>.ÔÇØ I lifted it up and he told me to raise it higher and I
did so. Some of the people said, ÔÇ£To where should it be raised?ÔÇØ The Prophet
 said, ÔÇ£<b>In the middle of the shins</b>.ÔÇØ</p>
```

I am wondering if you would be able to help me get rid of the **`<p>, </p> and <b>`**

**Code:**

```
url1 = "http://www.dailyhadithonline.com/2013/07/21/hadith-on-clothing-the-lower-garment-should-be-hallway-between-the-shins/"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1) 
english_hadith = soup.findAll('p')[0]
print english_hadith
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using regular expressions rather than `beautifulsoup.`

```
>>> import re
>>> a='<p>dhhdhd<p>dhdhd</p>'
>>> re.sub('<p>|</p>','',a)
'dhhdhddhdhd'
```

A more general regular expression would be

```
re.sub('<p[^>]*>|</p>','',a)
```

Comment: Why? regex sucks for parsing html. What if there are other possibly nested tags?

Comment: i believe the OP needed to eliminate just `p` and `b` tags,as per the text example given

Comment: @rjv: A larger issue would be things like: `<p style="text-align:center;">` and `<p data-foo=bar>`. But that doesn't appear to be a problem for Ossama.

Comment: you will have to modify the regexp in that case

Comment: Which is another reason to just use BeautifulSoup in the first place

Comment: i have modified the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [nltk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk).

Example:

```
from nltk import clean_html
html = "..."
clean_html(html)
```

Comment: nltk is a best library to remove html tags.

Comment: But Avoid package external python library, If you can use python module like re for this.  If there is no option in python, then only you can use external python library

Comment: Sure you could write some hand-written code, or borrow someone else's but there are nicely libraries for this such as nltk that just do the job for you :) (*why re-invent the wheel?*)

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

```
print english_hadith.text
```

Displays:

> Ibn Umar reported: I passed by the Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, while my garment was trailing. The Prophet said, “O Abdullah, raise your garment.” I lifted it up and he told me to raise it higher and I did so. Some of the people said, “To where should it be raised?” The Prophet said, “In the middle of the shins.”

Comment: I get the following UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position
 137: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Ossama, what is your `sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: @Ossama, `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: the sys.stdout.encoding is cp850

Comment: @Ossama, Your problem is that [your terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) doesn't support the fancy quote characters.

Comment: Thanks.I'll try at me home computer latter. thanks for you help

Comment: @Ossama, [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650369/php-utf-8-to-msdos-command-line-encoding) provides a possible workaround