# How to convert output of windows shell exec in php to utf8

Tags: php, windows, shell, utf-8, cmd

I'm trying to convert the output of one of the commands in PHP that execute shell to utf8 because json_encode returns an empty string.

I've tried to use `mb_detect_encoding` to detect encoding and I wanted to use `mb_convert_encoding` but `mb_detect_encoding` is returning empty string.

I've got output like this:

```
2016-04-29  10:09         2�216�720 0.8.1.zip
```

I've also tried this:

```
sapi_windows_cp_conv(sapi_windows_cp_get(), 65001, $output);
```

but this return:

```
sapi_windows_cp_conv(): Wide char conversion failed
```

Output code page found in this question [PHP UTF-8 to Windows command line encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650369/php-utf-8-to-windows-command-line-encoding)

Also tried to convert to utf8 before I'm executing dir using:

```
shell_exec('chcp 65001 && dir');
```

but I've got the same results, weird � instead of space and empty mb_detect.

How can I convert the output of shell command on windows to UTF8?

Comment: What encoding does the shell use? maybe `echo $LANG` have encoding infos.

Comment: @Mat it's windows cmd.exe not unix.

Comment: Could we get some inputs that are generating that output? Also see [what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

Comment: @Tzalumen It's output of `dir` and the chcp was something like 47x, I don't have access to that windows machine right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function `sapi_windows_cp_get()` accept string as argument

```
$output = sapi_windows_cp_conv(sapi_windows_cp_get('oem'), 65001, $output);
```